# Can I use excel logic function "if" in DataTable or dataGridView?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a program in VB.NET with a table which would like to run the excel logic function "if" to complete the third column:

My code for DT and DGV

```
Dim DGV As New DataGridView
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    If DGV.ColumnCount > 0 Then
        Try
            DT.Columns.Remove("Nº")
            DT.Columns.Remove("Q")
            DT.Columns.Remove("k")
            DT.Clear()
        Catch g As DataException
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Of type {0} occurred.", g.GetType().ToString())
        End Try
    End If
    DGV.SetBounds(12, 120, 865, 460)
    Controls.Add(DGV)
    DT.Columns.Add("Nº", GetType(Int32))
    DT.Columns.Add("Q", GetType(Double))
    DT.Columns.Add("k", GetType(String))
    For I = 1 To 100
        DT.Rows.Add(I, I * 3)
    Next (I)
    Me.DGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader
    DGV.ReadOnly = True
    DGV.DataSource = DT
```

It's possible? Examples in C# also are accepts.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible what? What should be the value for the column k?

Comment: Hi @Steve In the column that will be applied the "if", for example: SE (Q> = 50; "Yes"; "Not"). The "No." column is for numbers.

Comment: Check the DataColumn.Expression property and its syntax (IIF function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
DataColumn dc = DT.Columns.Add("k", GetType(String))
dc.Expression = "IIF(Q >= 50; 'Yes'; 'Not')"
```

or directly in the creation of the column

```
DT.Columns.Add("k", GetType(String), "IIF(Q >= 50; 'Yes'; 'Not'")
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. : D @Steve